# How to give a href link while submitting a form in php

Tags: php, opencart

Actually while inserting the data into database iam passing the link to  redirect that to another page but it is not  submitting the form can any one help me regarding that...Please find the below link which i used

```
<div>
<textarea  name="comments"  rows="2" cols="100" placeholder="comments..."></textarea><br/>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-default pull-right"  
    href="<?php echo button_link."/details&cusid=".$orderdetail['customer_order_id'];?>" role="button">Submit</a>
```

Comment: It will not submit the form. <a> tag is used for navigation between pages.

Comment: hi can any one help me After submission of a record it should display only that  details of a customer ...

Answer (score 1):

`/details&cusid=`  is incorrect,  should be `/details?cusid=`

First query string parameter comes after `?` sign, not after  `&` sign. That is why your `/details` page is not seeing `cusid` value.

Comment: Yesterday it is working but now it is not working dont know what is the problem

Comment: There is no guesswork in programming logic. Either it works or it doesn't. When it doesn't you have to go through your code and find out what's wrong and fix it, not guess or stress.

Comment: If i use ? mark instead of & it is displaying as page not found and the data is also not inserting

Comment: Please add the output of your php code to your question, so we can see the complete link generated.

Comment: i used to add the comments in the database and according to the ids iam displaying the results see the above code i have modified that...

Answer (score 0):

Change your url:

```
"/details&cusid=".$orderdetail['customer_order_id'] to "/details?cusid=".$orderdetail['customer_order_id']
```

If you want to display the data use `$id = $_GET['cusid'];`

```
Select * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname = $id;
```

Comment: "/details?cusid=".$orderdetail['customer_order_id']  used this function it is getting as page requested not found    $id = $_GET['cusid'];   AFter submitting the form it should show that results directly

Comment: After inserting the record, you have the id of last inserted record. Use SQL query to retrieve the details of last inserted record.